# Upload large video (8GB) to Azure Blob storage from Angular 8 using REST PUT

Tags: angular, rest, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying many different methods to get very large video files (8GB) into an Azure storage container.

The solution I've landed on is uploading directly from an Angular 8 component using the Azure Storage REST API.

This is working fine for smaller files, but when I try to upload an 8GB file, it fails consistently at about 8% with the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure what i'm missing. Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
  onFileChange(event) {
     this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
     this.upload();
  }


  upload() {
    this.uploading = true;
    this.percentComplete = 1;
    let url = this.uploadUrl.split('?');
    let uploadUrl = url[0] + '/' + this.currentFile.name + '?' + url[1];

    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', uploadUrl, this.currentFile, {
      reportProgress: true,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob' })
    });

    this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
      // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
      // Look for upload progress events.
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
        let percentDone = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
        if (percentDone === 0) {
          percentDone = 1;
        }
        console.log(event.loaded + ' of ' + event.total);
        this.percentComplete = percentDone;
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.uploading = false;
        if (event.status === 201) {

          this.successEventHandler(event);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

**html**

```
<input [promiseBtn]="uploading" (change)="onFileChange($event)" id="fileAttachmentBtn" name="file-attachment" type="file" class="file-attachment-btn__label" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not hitting the Block Blob size limits for `PUT` operations? `The maximum size for a block blob created via Put Blob is 256 MB for version 2016-05-31 and later, and 64 MB for older versions. If your blob is larger than 256 MB for version 2016-05-31 and later, or 64 MB for older versions, you must upload it as a set of blocks.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest you use Azure Storage SDK for Node.JS. The SDK will handle all the works for you. Here are some samples for your references: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/tree/master/examples

Then, if you still want to upload the blob with REST API, then you need:

#### 1. Read the whole file to bytes, and divide the file into smaller pieces in your code.

- Maybe 8 MB for each pieces.

#### 2. Upload each piece with [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) API.

- In each request, it contains a blockid.

#### 3. Make up the blob with [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) API.

- In this request, you need to put all the blockid in the body in ordered.

Comment: Thanks. I found this example which I was able to tailor to my needs. https://medium.com/@stuarttottle/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-angular-7977e979496a