# Can not transfer more than 250MB with DataBufferUtils.write to Azure Blob Storage - Spring Webflux usage correct?

Tags: spring, azure, azure-blob-storage, spring-webflux

I like to stream large data files over REST directly to a Azure Blob Storage.
Now i face the problem that when I send a filter with 250MB over REST to the Azure Blob Storage, but with 260MB it stuck for ever.

I made an example Project where you can verify this behavior. https://github.com/git9999999/azure-blob-large-file-upload-problem

Question is my Reactive Code correct?

https://github.com/git9999999/azure-blob-large-file-upload-problem/blob/main/downloader/src/main/java/com/azureproblem/blob/controller/AzureBlobBugDownloaderController.java#L131

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/trigger-download-to-blob/{fileSizeInMb}")
    public void triggerDownloadToBlob(@PathVariable int fileSizeInMb) {
        log.info("triggerDownload");

        var flux = this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/serve-file/" + fileSizeInMb)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .exchangeToFlux(clientResponse -> clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()));

        var destination = "TestDownloadToAzureBlobStorage" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf";

        var blobClientTarget = this.containerClient.getBlobClient(destination);

        try (var outputStream = blobClientTarget.getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream(this.parallelTransferOptions, null, null, null, null)) {
            DataBufferUtils.write(flux, outputStream)
                .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
                .blockLast(Duration.ofHours(22));
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        log.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   end download of {}", destination);
    }
```

Comment: Does this resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636249/upload-large-video-8gb-to-azure-blob-storage-from-angular-8-using-rest-put

Comment: @AnupamChand I can not change the sender. So using a PUT is not an option. But thanks for the response :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I used the `BlobContainerClient` and not the `BlobContainerAsyncClient`. The `BlobContainerAsyncClient` has special API's to handle the Flux-"Stuff"

Hear is the code that I use now:

```
 public void uploadAsync(Flux<DataBuffer> flux, Path destination) {
        BlobAsyncClient blobClientTarget = this.blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient(relativePathUnix(destination));
        blobClientTarget.upload(flux.map((dataBuffer) -> {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(dataBuffer.readableByteCount());
            dataBuffer.toByteBuffer(buffer);
            DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
            return buffer;
        }), this.parallelTransferOptions).block();
    }
```

And Here is the Example repo with solution https://github.com/git9999999/azure-blob-large-file-upload-problem

Here the Ticket that solve the Problem: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/35477

Answer (score 0):

- The `uploadFile` method now accepts a `Flux<DataBuffer>` directly as a request part instead of using `MultipartFile`
- The file data is streamed using reactive programming with `DataBufferUtils.write`, Check the below code:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;

@Controller
public class AzureBlobUploaderController {

    private final AzureBlobContainerClient containerClient;
    private final int bufferSize;
    private final int timeoutSeconds;

    public AzureBlobUploaderController(@Value("${azure.storage.containerName}") String containerName,
                                       @Value("${bufferSize}") int bufferSize,
                                       @Value("${timeoutSeconds}") int timeoutSeconds) {
        this.containerClient = new AzureBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        this.timeoutSeconds = timeoutSeconds;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Create the container if it doesn't exist
        if (!containerClient.exists()) {
            containerClient.create();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/upload")
    public void uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") Flux<DataBuffer> file) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();

        String destinationBlobName = "UploadedFile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".bin";
        var blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(destinationBlobName);
        var blobOutputStream = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient().getBlobOutputStream();

        DataBufferUtils.write(file, blobOutputStream, bufferSize)
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    // Handle the error gracefully
                    stopWatch.stop();
                    System.out.println("Error occurred during data streaming: " + throwable.getMessage());
                })
                .doFinally(signal -> {
                    try {
                        blobOutputStream.flush();
                        blobOutputStream.close();
                        stopWatch.stop();
                        System.out.println("File uploaded successfully " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + "ms");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error occurred while closing the output stream: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                })
                .blockLast(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutSeconds));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace with your Azure Blob Storage container name
        String containerName = "your-container-name";

        // Replace with your buffer size and timeout settings
        int bufferSize = ;
        int timeoutSeconds = ;

        AzureBlobUploaderController controller = new AzureBlobUploaderController(containerName, bufferSize, timeoutSeconds);
    }
}
```

**Output :**
[image]

- Here by the post request, I am able to upload the 1GB file to my blob container.

[image]

- Here I am able to see the file in my container.

[image]

[image]

**Updated code:**

```
public Mono<Void> uploadFileToBlobStorage(WebClient webClient, String containerName, String blobName, File file) {
    return webClient.put()
            .uri("/" + containerName + "/" + blobName)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(file.length()))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(getFileDataBufferFlux(file), DataBuffer.class))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class);
}

private Flux<DataBuffer> getFileDataBufferFlux(File file) {
    return DataBufferUtils.read(FileChannel::open, file.toPath(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            .doFinally(signalType -> file.delete()); // Delete the file after reading its data
}
```

- The **getFileDataBufferFlux** reads the file in a reactive manner, returning a `Flux<DataBuffer>` the **uploadFileToBlobStorage** method uses the `WebClient` to perform a PUT request with the file's data as the request body.

Comment: thanks a lot for you effort to solve this problem :-) 
1) My method triggerDownloadToBlob is not triggered by an incoming REST call. I have to call it in my Program. => so i have to use the webclient. 2) I am using Azurite, the DockerContainer, as i check with Microsoft, this should not be the problem. Never the less it is a different to your code.

Comment: 3) I added part of your example to my repo https://github.com/git9999999/azure-blob-large-file-upload-problem/blob/main/downloader/src/main/java/com/azureproblem/blob/controller/AzureBlobBugDownloaderController.java#L162 4) I tested this new code and it did not solve my problem :-( 5) so either it is because of Azurite or because you get the Flux<DataBuffer> as a Parameter and tot from the webclient. 6) would it be possible to use the webclient in your example?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the WebClient in combination with reactive streams to upload files to Azure Blob Storage. use the body(BodyInserters) method to pass a Flux<DataBuffer> as the request body when uploading files.

Comment: As you know that Azuite has its default limitations like min-100mb, max-256mb. Please verify that the config of setting limitations as per the requirement.

once check my updated code in my answer where it is useful to you.